# Tabs organizing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any add-in for VS 2010 to make a tabs in two or more rows? Or any better idea how to organize my tabs if i work with many open windows simultaneously?

I tried to use vertical orientated tabs, but i don't like how much space they take up the width (*reduced a space for code editor*).

Maybe something like tabsstudio, but free...?

Thanks